# Verify a Table's existence when creating a View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to conditionally create Views in SQL Server 2008.  I'm familiar with using logic to test for table existence before creating tables, and for stored procedure existence when creating SPs.  What I need to do is check for the existence of a **table** before creating a **View**, so that the View can perform some useful joins only if all tables are present.

Owing to the first-statement-in-a-batch requirement, I've not been able to use the same techniques that I've used with tables and SPs.  The closest I've gotten to an error-free script is the second option provided by EzLo in answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49148251/how-to-check-if-a-view-exists-and-create-if-it-does-not).

Sample code looks something like this:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    AND TABLE_Name = 'Users')
    BEGIN
    DECLARE @V VARCHAR(max) = '
    CREATE VIEW [dbo].[UserContactsView]
    AS
    SELECT dbo.Users.ID, ... dbo.Contacts.Title
    FROM dbo.Users INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Users.ContactID = dbo.Contacts.ID ... '
    EXEC(@V)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
    /* declare another parameter with a slightly different View 
structure that omits references to the Users table */
```

The problem is that the logic does not appear to work.  Even though the Users table does not currently exist in my dev database, the first conditional block is being executed, with the result that an "Invalid object name 'dbo.Users'" error is occurring when the script is run.

I presume that there's something wrong with the way I'm approaching the logic.  Every other topic I've so far examined has focused on checking for existence of Views rather than tables, so I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

For clarification, this is a sort of interim step I'm taking for development and debugging purposes.  The complete database script will include all the "layers," so the Users table will always be present in Prod, meaning the second, complete version of the View should result.  But while working on the Contacts component, I'd like to work with a more lightweight version of the script and resulting database, which is **much** smaller than the whole.  If there's no way around this issue, I'll just move on to the unwieldy version and keep trucking.

Comment: Your query looks fine. is the `Users` table under schema `dbo` ?

Comment: *"Your query looks fine."* With the exception of it's using 3+ part naming for columns which is to be [Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). ;) You are far better off aliasing your objects in the `FROM` and using those to qualify your columns. This avoids the use of a feature that will be deprecated and possibly removed in a future version, and makes your code much more succinct and readable.

Comment: Users is under dbo in the Application database, which is normally an underlying layer of the Contacts database...but which isn't included in the dev instance I'm working with.

Comment: I can pretty easily eliminate the 3-part naming and re-run the script.  Will try that and evaluate the results...marking this as Answered if I can get past it.

Comment: OK, the error is still occurring at the same spot, and there's a new wrinkle...the call to sp_fulltext_database is now broken.  I guess that means there's *one* spot where "[dbo]. " should still exist.

Comment: (Sorry for the multitude of comments.  I keep hitting Enter to start a new paragraph, and instead submitting a comment.)

I have not yet applied the "aliasing your objects" suggestion, so I'm working on that now.

Comment: I'm going to check back periodically to see if any additional suggestions come up, but for the time being I think I'm going to work around this by moving the View creation out to separate scripts I can use to patch the completed DB...one for use with the full setup, and one for the Dev partial instance.

Thanks all around!

Comment: Are the two objects, `dbo.Users` and `dbo.UserContactsView` in the same database? You mention two databases, `Application` and `Contacts`, in your comments.

Comment: They are intended to both be in the complete database.  The full script is quite large, so it has been broken into "layers" to be applied, one at a time, during development as their respective component suites are completed.  That's why the conditional exists:  to create the View one way *if* all the tables are present, and to create it in a different way if only one table is there.  Hence the issue.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue. https://dbfiddle.uk/fEIi2r4M  Is it possible that you missed a stray reference to `dbo.Users` in this part? 
`/* declare another parameter with a slightly different View 
structure that omits references to the Users table */`

Comment: It's possible.  I've substantially changed the script since posting the question, so any answers I give about what I might have missed will be from struggling long-term memory.  

I have noticed a tendency to use bad escaping when moving the script into a parameter for exec, and that may have caused some problems that were confusing this issue.

Comment: I'm going to consider this resolved (not sure whether I should mark this as Answered, since the actual issue I was asking about remains unsolved, although I think--based on Eric Brandt's reply above, that I know what was really happening).

When running the script in SSMS, I got the abovementioned error, and when I double-clicked the error message, the script window highlighted the conditional statement, as if that's where the error was.  The problem was actually, evidently, a stray reference to a table in the "else" version of the view.

Also:  can someone explain the -1 to me?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [`object_id()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql) for these types of conditionals.

```
if object_id('dbo.Users', 'U') is not null begin
    -- do some stuff here
end
```

Comment: Thanks; I'll give that a shot on Monday or thereabouts to see if it can improve matters on other scripts.  I've used the "patch" method to get past the issue on this one.